# How to listen on events on react with plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If you go here: http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html you will find tutorials in jsx but how do I use only js?

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var TodoList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var createItem = function(itemText) {
      return <li>{itemText}</li>;
    };
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
  }
});
var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: [], text: ''};
  },
  onChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextItems = this.state.items.concat([this.state.text]);
    var nextText = '';
    this.setState({items: nextItems, text: nextText});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>TODO</h3>
        <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.text} />
          <button>{'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1)}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.renderComponent(<TodoApp />, mountNode);
```

For example the above code is using a listener, how do I do that in plain javascript?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just found this: http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var TodoList = React.createClass({displayName: 'TodoList',
  render: function() {
    var createItem = function(itemText) {
      return React.DOM.li(null, itemText);
    };
    return React.DOM.ul(null, this.props.items.map(createItem));
  }
});
var TodoApp = React.createClass({displayName: 'TodoApp',
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: [], text: ''};
  },
  onChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextItems = this.state.items.concat([this.state.text]);
    var nextText = '';
    this.setState({items: nextItems, text: nextText});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      React.DOM.div(null, 
        React.DOM.h3(null, "TODO"),
        TodoList( {items:this.state.items} ),
        React.DOM.form( {onSubmit:this.handleSubmit}, 
          React.DOM.input( {onChange:this.onChange, value:this.state.text} ),
          React.DOM.button(null, 'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1))
        )
      )
    );
  }
});
React.renderComponent(TodoApp(null ), mountNode);
```